# Trotz + genitive / dative plural?

Tags: dative, genitive

I know **trotz** should be used with genitive, e.g:

> Trotz des Regens gehe ich zur Schule.

But, I don't understand the case in the example below. It is not dative for plural, as **Freunde** not **Freunden**. Also not genitive for plural, **der neuen** not **des neuen**.

> Trotz der neuen Freunde hat sie oft Heimweh.

Comment: You seem to be looking at the wrong column in the declension table: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives#Weak_inflection

Comment: *des neuen* would be male or neuter genitive singular, *der neuen* is genitive plural

Comment: @DavidVogt ah, right. I was wrong with genitive plural. Tut mir leid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In spite of the new friends, she is often homesick.

Now, as far the genitive is concerned, you could have, for example:

> Das Messer des Mannes - The knife of the man.
> Der Wagen der Frau - The car of the woman.
> Der Zahn des Kindes - The tooth of the child.

Or, in the plural:

> Das Messer der Männer - The knife of the men.
> Der Wagen der Frauen - The car of the women.
> Der Zahn der Kinder - The tooth of the children.

Here are some examples with *trotz*:

> Trotz des Wetters fahren wir heute nach Hause - In spite of the weather, we're driving home today.
> Trotz meines Versuchs - Despite my attempt.
> ... trotz zahlreicher Proteste - ... notwithstanding numerous protests.
> Trotz intensiver Suche - Despite an intensive search.
> Trotz aller Bemühungen - Despite all efforts.

In summary:
*Trotz + des...* means that what follows is a masculine or neuter noun in the singular.
*Trotz + der...* could indicate either a feminine noun in the singular, or anything in the plural.

TL;DR: take a look at the following table https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/declension/genitive

Comment: It's **das** Messer here